# Converting a pandas nodes and edges list from node labels to node index

Tags: python, pandas, nodes, edges

I have a [tidy representation](https://www.data-imaginist.com/2017/introducing-tidygraph/) of a graph or network expressed as two separate csvs; one for nodes, one for edges with weights. I've read them from csv into pandas dataframes in Python 3.

I create some analogous dataframes using different methods here but use them for illustration of the problem.

```
import pandas as pd

# i have a nodes list
nodes = {'page': ['/', '/a', '/b']}
# the data is actually read in from csv
nodes = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(nodes)

nodes
```

Which returns the node list which has automatically been indexed by the default method (whatever that is; I read it varied between Python versions but that shouldn't impact the question).

```
    page
0   /
1   /a
2   /b
```

The edge list is:

```
# and an edges list which uses node label; source and destination
# need to convert into indexes from nodes
edges = {'source_node': ['/', '/a', '/b', '/a'],
        'destination_node': ['/b', '/b', '/', '/'],
        'weight': [5, 2, 10, 5]}
# the data is actually read in from csv
edges = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(edges)
edges
```

Which looks like:

```
    source_node destination_node    weight
0   /                   /b            5
1   /a                  /b            2
2   /b                  /             10
3   /a                  /             5
```

Here you see the problem, the source and destination nodes are the labels rather than the correct node indexes from the previous dataframe. I want an edge pandas dataframe with the appropriate indices of the labelled nodes rather than their labels. I could do this upstream in the data pipeline but want to fix this here for convenience. The number of nodes and edges are of 22 k and 45 k respectively. I don't mind if the solution takes a few minutes to run.

I can get the information I'm after but can't assign it to a new pandas column in the edges dataframe.

I can get the indexes I want by looping but is there a better way to do this in pandas, can I vectorise the problem like in R?

```
for i in edges["source_node"]:
    print(nodes[nodes.page == i].index.values.astype(int)[0])

for i in edges["destination_node"]:
    print(nodes[nodes.page == i].index.values.astype(int)[0])

0
1
2
1
2
2
0
0
```

And how to I get this into my edges dataframe as two new columns, one called 'source' and one called 'destination'. What I want is:

```
    source_node destination_node    weight    source      destination
0   /                   /b            5        0                2
1   /a                  /b            2        1                2
2   /b                  /             10       2                0
3   /a                  /             5        1                0
```

Doing the following errors and doesn't look right to begin with:

```
edges['source'] = for i in edges["source_node"]:
    nodes[nodes.page == i].index.values.astype(int)[0]

edges['destination'] = for i in edges["destination_node"]:
    nodes[nodes.page == i].index.values.astype(int)[0]
```

As I'm new to Python, I'd be interested in a "Pythonic" way of solving this, as well as a method which is simple to my newbie eyes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` and `set_index`:

```
nodelist = nodes.reset_index().set_index('page').squeeze()
```

Or @mammykins suggested for a real world sample use:

```
nodelist = nodelist.loc[~nodelist.index.duplicated(keep='first')]


edges['source'] = edges.source_node.map(nodelist)
edges['destination'] = edges.destination_node.map(nodelist)

print(edges)
```

Output:

```
  source_node destination_node  weight  source  destination
0           /               /b       5       0            2
1          /a               /b       2       1            2
2          /b                /      10       2            0
3          /a                /       5       1            0
```

Comment: This worked for the toy example above. My real data had duplicate rows which I removed with:  

    `nodelist = nodelist.loc[~nodelist.index.duplicated(keep='first')]`, prior to the `edges` new column assignment step. Is that worth adding to your answer @scott?